# SwiftUI - Double `.clipped()` modifier makes views disappear

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I have a view, `DotView`, which consists of 3 green circles [`clipped`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/clipped(antialiased:)) by a red border. I'm using [`DragGesture`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/draggesture) to slide it horizontally in a container view, which has a blue border and is also `clipped`.

The problem is, once I slide to a certain point, the 3 green circles disappear. **How can I prevent them from disappearing?** Interestingly, if I remove the first `clipped` and only clip the blue container, the circles don't disappear. Similarly, if I remove the second `clipped` and only clip `DotView`, they also don't disappear.

| Both views clipped | Only blue view clipped | Only `DotView` clipped |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Green circles disappear after sliding a bit] The green circles **disappear**. | [image: Green circles stay, but overflow the red border] The green circles **stay**. | [image: Green circles and red border both stay, but together they are not constrained to the blue border] The green circles **stay**. |

Here's my code:

```
/// 3 green circles, constrained to a red border
struct DotView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<3) { _ in
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 250)
        .border(Color.red)
        .clipped() /// 1. make sure the green circles don't overflow
    }
}

/// container for horizontal dragging, with a blue border
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var offset = CGFloat(0)
    var body: some View {
        DotView()
            .padding() /// add a small gap between the red and blue borders
            .offset(x: offset, y: 0)
            .border(Color.blue)
            .clipped() /// 2. make sure `DotView` doesn't overflow the blue border
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0) /// slide `DotView` left and right
                        .onChanged { offset = $0.translation.width }
            )
    }
}
```

The disappearing effect is very visible with `ForEach`, but occurs with other views too. For example, here's what happens when you replace the entire `HStack` with `Circle().fill(Color.green).frame(width: 100, height: 100)`:

[image: 1 circle disappears after nearing the edge]

Is there any way I can use `clipped` more than once, without getting weird side effects? How come they only disappear on the left side and not the right side?
Or maybe, `offset` is what's causing problems?

Comment: Your code works fine for me without any issue with xCode Version 12.5.1 (961.1). Can you try your own code and replace `.clipped()` with `.clipShape(Rectangle())` I think it can solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like drawing optimisation (and yes looks like it originated by `offset`).

Anyway, here is a fix - use drawing group to fix content (tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15):

```
var body: some View {
    DotView()
        .padding()
        .drawingGroup()               // << here !!
        .offset(x: offset, y: 0)
        .border(Color.blue)
        .clipped()
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0) /// slide `DotView` left and right
                .onChanged { offset = $0.translation.width }
        )
}
```