# Sliding card not showing transition from withAnimation { } block

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, gesture, uiswipegesturerecognizer

so I have a sliding card located at the bottom of the page. When it appears, it starts with the top of edge of the card at about halfway up the screen. I want to make it so that when I tap it or swipe down, it dismisses by animating a transition of the card to the bottom edge of the screen. The problem I'm running into is this. When I'm running the withAnimation { } block, the card is dismissing immediately (instantly disappearing) instead of animating the change by moving off the screen smoothly. How can I fix this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var appState: AppState = AppState()
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color.gray
            Text("Main View")
            SlideOverView(appState: appState, content: {
                VStack {
                    Text("Slide Over View")
                    Spacer()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

class AppState: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var showCard: Bool = false
}

struct SlideOverView<Content> : View where Content : View {
    @ObservedObject var appState: AppState
    var content: () -> Content
    
    init(appState: AppState, content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.appState = appState
        self.content = content
    }
     
    public var body: some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self.content(), modifier: CardView(appState: appState))
    }
}


struct CardView: ViewModifier {
    @ObservedObject var appState: AppState
    @State private var dragging = false
    @GestureState private var dragTracker: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        let position: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.4
        return ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            if appState.showCard {
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2.5)
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 5.0)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                        .padding(10)
                    content.padding(.top, 30)
                }.transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .top), removal: .move(edge: .bottom)))
                .frame(minWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: 1, anchor: .center)
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(15)
            }
        }
        .offset(y:  max(0, position + self.dragTracker.height))
        .animation({
            Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 250.0, damping: 40.0, initialVelocity: 5.0)
        }())
        .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .updating($dragTracker) { drag, state, transaction in state = drag.translation }
                    .onChanged {_ in  dragging = true }
                    .onEnded(onDragEnded))
        .onTapGesture {
            let low: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.4
            if position == low {
                withAnimation {
                    appState.showCard = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func onDragEnded(drag: DragGesture.Value) {
        dragging = false
        let dragDirection = drag.predictedEndLocation.y - drag.location.y
        if dragDirection > 0 {
            withAnimation {
                appState.showCard = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile. You left at least a couple `showCards` out of your code.

Comment: @Yrb I simplified it because I'm passing around an ObservedObject tracking the app state with lots of different variables in it, not sure where it's going wrong above but essentially I'm passing a binding variable between all the views.

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't debug it if we can't run it.

Comment: @Yrb Added the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Something about the view modifier seems to be breaking the transition. I greatly refactored your code, and can get the transition to work intermittently. I am thinking you found a bug, but I can't be sure without more testing. I would recommend ditching the view modifier if you need the transition. This should be working. Also, your modifier is a bit awkward. Paul Hegarty does this same sort of view modifier in [CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/), and builds it up through Lecture 7.

Comment: @Yrb Nothing I'm trying is working. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The issue seems to be twofold. First, it does not appear to work inside of the view modifier at all. I pulled it out of there, and set the transition and the animation with the conditional on the top view. At that point it works intermittently, but the animation doesn't trigger properly. My only thought is to ditch the view modifier and make it a simple view that your insert and remove in your hierarchy, if you want the transition.

Comment: Sometimes SwiftUI gets weird when you use `offset`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70043478/14351818

Comment: Works fine here. Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2. I assume that your issue is due to other code where this snapshot was extracted from, by itself as-is animations work fine in this example for both tap and drag.